# How to run macro on multiple files with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am relatively novice at VBA code, but I'm trying to make something work to run a recorded macro on multiple files. Below are two ways I've tried, but I keep getting the same error (running Microsoft 365 Excel on a Mac). Open to a solution, or an alternative method.

First, I found [this example](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/5332-excel-run-macro-multiple-workbooks.html):

```
Sub LoopThroughFiles()
    Dim xFd As FileDialog
    Dim xFdItem As Variant
    Dim xFileName As String
    Set xFd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If xFd.Show = -1 Then
        xFdItem = xFd.SelectedItems(1) & Application.PathSeparator
        xFileName = Dir(xFdItem & "*.xls*")
        Do While xFileName <> ""
            With Workbooks.Open(xFdItem & xFileName)
                'your code here
            End With
            xFileName = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End Sub
```

However, when I try running it, I keep getting an error as follows: "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set"

I later found [this tutorial](https://www.educba.com/vba-filedialog/) with the following code and tried running it, meeting with the same error.

```
Sub SelectFile()

Dim File As FileDialog
Set File = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With File
.Filters.Clear
.AllowMultiSelect = False
.Show
End With

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://anywarellc.com/2021/03/31/excel-vba-file-dialog-on-a-mac/

Comment: This link seems relevant. I get that MacOS has some other way of getting the file path, besides "Application.FileDialog", but what specifically from this guy's code am I supposed to use to do that, and how does it fit into the current code? It feels a little over my head :/

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/hh710200(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN is maybe more useful (see sub "Select_File_Or_Files_Mac").  I don't have a mac to test with though.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much @TimWilliams. This looks like just what I need. Also, I at least realized that, since the problem is PC/Mac, I can easily use the original code if I just run things on my wife's substantially cheaper (but correct OS) PC ;)